# Laravel y el tratamiento de fechas

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Señores estoy obteniendo una fecha en este formato DD/MM/YYYY, y como estoy usando MYSQL tengo que guardarla en YYYY-MM-DD.

El asunto es que estoy usando eloquent y estoy haciendo algo asi:

```
public function create(Request $request)
$tabla=new Tabla();
$tabla->fecha=$request->fecha
$tabla->save();
```

aqui

```
$request->fecha
```

Estoy recibiendo '20/02/2018' y necesito guardarla '2018-20-02' como lo puedo hacer?

Answer (score 2):

Utiliza Carbon y sus herramientas de creación y formateo para generar la fecha:

```
public function create(Request $request)
{
    $tabla = new Tabla();

    $fecha = Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $request->fecha)->toDateString();
    $fecha = $tabla->fecha;

    $tabla->save();
}
```

Explicación: primero generas una fecha según el formato que tienes con el método `createFromFormat()` y posteriormente el método `toDateString()` va a convertir dicho resultado a yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: Gracias me has ayudado con tu respuesta

Comment: Si la respuesta te sirvió, puedes marcarla como aceptada.